# UITableView dynamic height is always 0

Tags: ios, height, tableview

I'm using a TableView and a Collection View in a Scroll View. I set scrolling disabled in the Table View so i need to change the height of the Table View.

I used this code to get the height, but every height was 0

```
//NSUInteger tableViewheight = self.videosArray.count * 60;  //60 is the cell height

NSUInteger tableViewHeight = self.videosTableView.contentSize.height;

CGRect frame;
frame = self.videosTableView.frame;
frame.size.height = tableViewHeight;
self.videosTableView.frame = frame;
```

I also tried the commented code above.

Anyone an idea how i can get the height or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: when do you try this? the cell's contentView height inst valid before it is displayed.

Comment: once see my updated answer.

Comment: Is height of each cell fixed or dynamic?

Comment: i have this in the view will appear method after all the tableview methods.

the cell height is fixed (60 px)

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: show me your .h file code?

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Your tableview has section?

Comment: yes one section as normal

Comment: Problem is solved!

I had everything in ViewWillAppear, I tried ViewDidLoad too.

But now i have it in ViewDidAppear and everything is working fine. And thanks for all your help!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
heightRateTbl = [myArray count] * 60;

rateTableView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, heightRateTbl);  

rateTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

rateTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[rateTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: And if the datasource array has a count of 100? According to this, that would make the table 6,000 points high.

Comment: Set tableView scrolleble it solved your problem

rateTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: You're thinking of `contentSize`, not `frame.size.height`.

Comment: it also doesnt work because my self.array.count is 0 but a few lines above i use the same for the numberOfRowsInSection method. return self.array.count and it works. I dont understand why its a few lines below 0...

Comment: You should use my code in viewDidLoad method after you get your array or declare your array. numberOfRowsInSection is show the number of lines(cell) which you can select in table view. if you get your right answer then please upvote for me.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Your array count is zero so it's not working first insert some value in your array then try it worked.

Comment: @ChiragPipaliya yes i put the code in ViewDidAppear and everything worked. thanks for your help!

Comment: @DanielKappacher : Your most welcome my friend if you got your answer than you should give me upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should have try following code to set frame:-

```
[self.videosTableView reloadData];
float tableViewHeight = self.videosTableView.contentSize.height;
CGRect frame = self.videosTableView.frame;
self.videosTableView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, tableViewHeight, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"tableViewheight height = %f",tableViewheight);
NSLog(@"videosTableView height = %f",self.videosTableView.frame.size.height);
```

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: @DanielKappacher : Have you tried above code? Let me know what happen?

Comment: yes, but it gives me just the height i added in storyboard, and not the height dynamic height the table view is high.

Comment: Have you tried with float tableViewHeight = self.videosTableView.contentSize.height; instead of float tableViewheight = self.videosArray.count * 60; ?

Comment: what here you get? NSLog(@"tableViewheight height = %f",tableViewheight);

Comment: First you have to reload tableview then you should check contentSize of tableview.

Comment: 2013-03-30 14:06:56.400 Nine Knights[40837:c07] 0.00000